# Error printing specific page range in microsoft word in c++ app

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, ms-word

I have a strange problem where I'm trying to print a specific page range in microsoft word from a console app and I'm seeing strange results and I'm assuming it's something I did incorrectly when specifying a page range.

It appears that after I print a page range and go to get the total number of pages in the word document this number varies after I print specific ranges.  Another weird thing is that this works in debug mode but not in release mode.

ex.
Word document consists of 2 pages
Print page 1-1. 
Get number of pages returns 2

Print page 2-2
Get number of pages returns 1

Code is below for printing a range of pages:

```
int CWordComm::PrintAndCloseActiveDocument(int iNumOfCopies, short nTray, int pageNumber)
{
    // Convenient values declared as ColeVariants.
    COleVariant covTrue((short)TRUE), covFalse((short)FALSE), covOptional((long)DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);

    _Document oActiveDoc = m_oWord.GetActiveDocument();

    if(!this->m_szOutputFilename.IsEmpty())
    {
        //If we are outputting the document to a file then we need to print a single page at a time
        //This is because of a limitation on the ikonprinter/requisition printer side that can only handle
        //one page at a time
        // Print out to file
        CString szCurrentPage, szPrintRange;
        szCurrentPage.Format("%d", pageNumber);
        szPrintRange.Format("%d", PRINT_FROM_TO);  //PRINT_FROM_TO is #define PRINT_FROM_TO 3

        COleVariant printRange(szPrintRange, VT_BSTR);
        COleVariant currentPage(szCurrentPage, VT_BSTR);

        sprintf(m_szLogMessage, "Printing page %d of requisition", pageNumber);
        LogMessage(m_szLogMessage);

        oActiveDoc.PrintOut(covFalse,          // Background.
            covOptional,           // Append.
            printRange,             // Range.
            COleVariant(szFileName,VT_BSTR),  // OutputFileName.
            currentPage,           // From.
            currentPage,           // To.
            covOptional,           // Item.
            COleVariant((long)1),  // Copies.
            covOptional,           // Pages.
            covOptional,           // PageType.
            covTrue,               // PrintToFile.
            covOptional,           // Collate.
            covOptional,           // ActivePrinterMacGX.
            covOptional            // ManualDuplexPrint.
            );
    }
    else
    {
        // Print out to file
        oActiveDoc.PrintOut(covFalse,          // Background.
            covOptional,           // Append.
            covOptional,           // Range.
            COleVariant(szFileName,VT_BSTR),  // OutputFileName.
            covOptional,           // From.
            covOptional,           // To.
            covOptional,           // Item.
            COleVariant((long)1),  // Copies.
            covOptional,           // Pages.
            covOptional,           // PageType.
            covTrue,               // PrintToFile.
            covOptional,           // Collate.
            covOptional,           // ActivePrinterMacGX.
            covOptional            // ManualDuplexPrint.
            );
    }

    //Get the number of pages in the word document
    iNumPages=GetActiveDocPageCount();

    //omitted code
}
```

Get pages method

```
int CWordComm::GetActiveDocPageCount()
{
    try
    {
        _Document oActiveDoc; 
        //Get the Active Document
        oActiveDoc = m_oWord.GetActiveDocument();

        //Get the BuiltinDocumentProperties collection for the 
        //document
        LPDISPATCH lpdispProps;
        lpdispProps = oActiveDoc.GetBuiltInDocumentProperties();

        //Get the requested Item from the BuiltinDocumentProperties 
        //collection
        //NOTE:  The DISPID of the "Item" property of a 
        //       DocumentProperties object is 0x0
        VARIANT vResult;
        DISPPARAMS dpItem;
        VARIANT vArgs[1];
        vArgs[0].vt = VT_BSTR;

        //property name for the number of pages in the active document
        _bstr_t btVal("Number of pages");

        vArgs[0].bstrVal = btVal;
        dpItem.cArgs=1;
        dpItem.cNamedArgs=0;
        dpItem.rgvarg = vArgs;
        HRESULT hr = lpdispProps->Invoke(0x0, IID_NULL, 
            LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, 
            &dpItem, &vResult, NULL, NULL);

        //Get the Value property of the BuiltinDocumentProperty
        //NOTE:  The DISPID of the "Value" property of a 
        //       DocumentProperty object is 0x0
        DISPPARAMS dpNoArgs = {NULL, NULL, 0, 0};
        LPDISPATCH lpdispProp;
        lpdispProp = vResult.pdispVal;
        hr = lpdispProp->Invoke(0x0, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 
            DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, &dpNoArgs, &vResult, 
            NULL, NULL);

        CString sPropValue = "";
        switch (vResult.vt)
        {
        case VT_BSTR:
            sPropValue = vResult.bstrVal;
            break;
        case VT_I4:
            sPropValue.Format("%d",vResult.lVal);
            break;
        case VT_DATE:
            {
                COleDateTime dt (vResult);
                sPropValue = dt.Format(0, LANG_USER_DEFAULT);
                break;
            }
        default:
//          sPropValue = "<Information for the property you selected is not available>";
            sPropValue = "-4";
            break;
        }

        //Release the no longer needed IDispatch pointers
        lpdispProp->Release();
        lpdispProps->Release();

        return atoi(sPropValue);

    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return FUNC_ERROR;
    }
}
```

### Question

**Is there something obvious I am doing wrong here?  Should I be interfacing with word in a different way if I wish to print a range of pages?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is some sort of timing issue.  I put a 500ms sleep after the printing of the document and before the calculation of the number of pages and I'm now consistently getting the correct results.

When I was debugging it was essentially doing this same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine in the debug mode, I suggest you write the values ( eg No of pages, page being printed etc ) to a text file. Compare the debug log output , with the release log output. Here's a [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176069) which might help you. The link is not in C++, but might guide you in the right way.